# CoinKite new/receive - passing correct parameters

Tags: php, api

I am trying to generate a `new/receive` BitCoin pubkey with `Coinkite API`. The problem is that API rejects my call with an error message of `Bad Request` and some kind of unexpected arguments for the mandatory arguments.

```
$endpoint='/v1/new/receive';
$url='https://api.coinkite.com'.$endpoint;
$sign = CKsign($endpoint);

$API_KEY = 'KebXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("X-CK-Key: {$API_KEY}", "X-CK-Sign: {$sign[0]}", "X-CK-Timestamp: {$sign[1]}"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
$data = array('memo' => 'test pubkey 1', 'account' => '1FXXXXXX-XXXXXX');
//$data = array(array("memo","test pubkey 1"), array("account","1F3A7E22A8-51F278"));
$data = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

The error message I get is:

```
{ "help_msg": "Unexpected arg(s): {\"memo\":\"test pubkey 
1\",\"account\":\"1FXXXXXX-XXXXXX\"}", "message": "Bad Request", "status": 
400 }
```

The line which is commented, the dummy vector,  gives the same error and I don't understand why this is happening since these are mandatory arguments. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Omit "$data = json_encode($data);". Found the solution in https://github.com/coinkite/coinkite-php/blob/master/lib/CKRequestor.php : "$args = JSON document or an array of arguments".

Comment: thanks alot, that worked and the library you suggested seems  to be very usefull. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1) First step for issues like this is to check out the "Debug live-stream". It shows all the arguments, most headers, results, and error messages for everything happening with an API key.

Go to Tools > API Keys and look for the magic wand:

[image]

2) Specifically in your case here, there is nothing wrong with "memo" and "account" and they are valid argument to this command. I think the problem is the encoding of your data. I think it's sending it as form data? You should use JSON instead. Coinkite recommends PUT of JSON (including a correct Content-Type header line of: `application/json`). Take a peek at the debug live-stream and see how the server sees your data to check this is the problem.

Hope that helps!