# Encoding array using JSON in PHP [Bitcoin | CoinKite]

Tags: php, json, api, bitcoin

My project runs as a hidden service over TOR. Most of my customers use the TOR browser which does not support JS out of the box. I want to offer my customers the ability to make transactions using bitcoin but will have to generate a unique address for each of them. CoinKite generates HD wallet addresses according to the BIP32 specification and allows them to be requested through their API. Most of the API examples utilize JS and their PHP examples are messy and not very well documented. Here's what I currently have:

*Sign.php - takes care of the signing process using my API secret*

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
function sign($endpoint, $force_ts=false)
{
    $API_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    if($force_ts) {
        $ts = $force_ts;
    } else {
        $now = new DateTime();
        $ts = $now->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    }

    $data = $endpoint . '|' . $ts;
    $hm = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $API_SECRET);

    return array($hm, $ts);
}
?>
```

*Gen.php - Performs a PUT on CK's API and stores it's output in a variable.*

```
<?php
require('sign.php');

$endpoint='/v1/new/receive';
$url='http://api.gcvqzacplu4veul4.onion'.$endpoint;
$sign = sign($endpoint);
$API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("X-CK-Key: {$API_KEY}", "X-CK-Sign: {$sign[0]}", "X-CK-Timestamp: {$sign[1]}"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "localhost:8118");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');

$data = array('account' => 'xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx', 'amount' => 0.1);

$data = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
?>
```

*The response*

```
{ "help_msg": "Unexpected arg(s): {\"account\":\"xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx\",\"amount\":0.1}", "message": "Bad Request", "status": 400 }
```

I've been scratching my head over this one for days now. CoinKite's debug interface doesn't show any information other than the response I got. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Account and amount are not arguments? You might want to contact them or at least give us the documentation link.

Comment: Documentation for /new/receive is on https://docs.coinkite.com/api/new-update.html?highlight=receive

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843269/coinkite-new-receive-passing-correct-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Almost want to hand myself a punch to the head now. Since CoinKite returns a JSON stream I mistakenly believed it also wanted to receive one. For others running into the same issue: omit the "$data = json_encode($data);" line, and you're good to go.